# Java program freaks out when user inputs parenthesis

Tags: java, input, arraylist, stringbuilder

I am making a simple calculator, however before I can do that, I need to make an algorithm to convert a user input into a consistent format. The user can input numbers and operators as well as parenthesis. The program has no problem dealing with numbers and operators, but for some unknown reason it throws an error whenever the loop encounters a parenthesis.

I have been attempting to debug the code for the past few hours, but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening?

```
/** These are the possible operators */
private static final String OPERATORS = "+-/*%^()[]{}";

/** This is an ArrayList of all the discrete
    things (operators/operands) making up an input.
    This is really just getting rid of the spaces,
    and dividing up the "stuff" into manageable pieces.
*/
static ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

public static ArrayList inputCleaner(String postfix) {
    StringBuilder poop = new StringBuilder();
    String doody = postfix.replace(" ", "");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < doody.length(); i++) {
            char c = doody.charAt(i);
            boolean isNum = (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
            if (isNum) {
                poop.append(c);
                if (i == doody.length() - 1) {
                    input.add(poop.toString());
                    poop.delete(0, poop.length());
                }
            }
            else if (c == '.') {
                for (int j = 0; j < poop.length(); j++) {
                    if (poop.charAt(j) == '.') {
                        throw new SyntaxErrorException("You can't have two decimals in a number.");
                    }
                    else if (j == poop.length() - 1) {
                        poop.append(c);
                    }
                } 
                if (i == doody.length() - 1) {
                    throw new SyntaxErrorException("You can't end your equation with a decimal!");
                }
            }
            else if (OPERATORS.indexOf(c) != -1 && poop.length() != 0) {
                input.add(poop.toString());
                poop.delete(0, poop.length());
                poop.append(c);
                input.add(poop.toString());
                poop.delete(0, poop.length());  
            }
            else {
                throw new SyntaxErrorException("Make sure your input only contains numbers, operators, or parantheses/brackets/braces.");
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
    catch (SyntaxErrorException exc) {
        System.out.println("That didn't work, something was wrong with the syntax.");
        return input;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList test = new ArrayList();
    Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please insert an argument: \n");
    String g = f.nextLine();
    test = inputCleaner(g);

    for (int z = 0; z < test.size(); z++) {
        System.out.println(test.get(z));
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you catch exactly? And which line is it thrown?

Comment: what error is thrown?

Comment: It throws the SyntaxErrorException. The weird part is that the error appears, then the program will print the contents of the ArrayList up to the parenthesis (the parenthesis are not included). The error is not thrown so long as no parenthesis are included. The program seems to be treating parenthesis differently than the other OPERATORS. That is why I am confused. The program works fine for -+*/%^.

Comment: Please use IDE and debug a bit.

Comment: That's what I've been doing.

Comment: When iterating over a parenthesis, in your `else if (OPERATORS.indexOf(c) != -1 && poop.length() != 0)`, `OPERATORS.indexOf(c)` returns `true` but `poop.length() != 0` returns `false`... There must be something wrong here ;)

Comment: That was totally it. Thanks, sp00m! Thanks everyone for taking a look, I know your time is important.

Comment: How should I have made it?

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is not very good coz I have no good explanation for it(due to brain overheat at work) but this change doesn't throw exception as in your case(might be an answer for you ;) )

Instead of using `poop.length() != 0` in the condition I have simply changed it to `poop != null` and voila... there are no `Exceptions` now. Comment if you can explain me this.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out! The issue was fixed in the comments portion of my original post.

Comment: I appreciate your concern, this is the lack of reputation only that I am unable to post a comment there. I thought that my answer above is somewhat between a comment and an actual answer. I'll keep your adive in mind ;) TY.